# Absolutely positioned element positioned where it would've been had it been static

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create an absolutely positioned element whose top/left is set to where it would've been had it been static, and whose bottom/right is set to 0px, 0px.

Thank you

Comment: are you talking about stretching an element by fixing the lower right corner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible but under certain conditions only. The element has to be inside a container element whose dimensions(effective width and height) should be same as the element container(a simple javascript can do that trick) and it should have {position: relative}.Make this container position itself as it's child would have been.That's it.